# Drawable and Android screen pixel density for fixed-size image

Tags: android, screen, drawable, pixel

I'm going through a problem in an application here my related to this issue. See if you can help me:

In my case I have a ImageView showing a ruler, and then I need to show this rule in real size, where it does not need to grow or shrink as the screen size or density. Using as a basis my Moto G3, it works perfectly, but when testo other devices, it loses the actual size of a ruler because the image tries to fit the screen size.

The image of the ruler is in PNG and measures 3600px x 155px and has measured up to 30cm, it is within a LinearLayout orizontal. In my Moto G3 visible area it is in 10cm, a larger screen for example it should show a larger area of ​​the ruler (11 to 15cm for example), but it contunua only 10cm in the visual field of the screen, showing that it grows and shrinks as the display settings and density of the device.

Before I had a picture of RAGUA for each resource (xxhdpi, xhdpi, etc), so I decided to migrate it to the assets folder of Android, but still with the same problem.

Do you have a light on how to fix it?

Follows the code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rulerPolegada"
            android:layout_width="1780dp"
            android:layout_height="103dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_ruler"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And as I said, after I image for assets, I started to set it in java:

```
rulerPolegada = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rulerPolegada);
        rulerPolegada.setImageDrawable(Controller.getImageAssets(getActivity(), "ruler_polegada.png"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Understanding Density Independence In Android](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android), you can calculate those values as follows

[image: this table]

Here is how you can calculate for your device (Moto G3)

1. 30cm = 11.811 in
2. Moto G3 screen density bucket is xhdpi - 320dpi
3. 320px ~= 1 in
4. 320px * 11.811in ~= 3780px

With this steps you can calculate how big your image should be.

Now, instead of providing different ruler's images for different screen densities, place your high quality image in drawable-anydpi folder, because `A drawable in res/drawable-anydpi/ also is valid for any screen density. However, in this case, the -anydpi variant trumps any density-specific variant.` due to ['-nodpi, -anydpi, and WTF?' article from The CommonsBlog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html)

Unfortunatelly, you can't used calculated values in layout xml file directly - ImageView size needs to be changed dynamically in Java code.

Above solution should give you **decent** accurancy (it can be diffent by 10%), but you can use DensityMetrics together with default display to get actual horizontal and vertical density, which will help you calculate image pixel size more precisely.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

// these will return the actual dpi horizontally and vertically
float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

**Edit**

Calculation for 480dp:

1. 30cm = 11.811 in
2. density bucket xxhdpi - 480dp
3. 480px ~= 1in
4. 480px * 11.811in ~= 5669px

Comment: Ok, see: this time my app has the follow data, e it is working well in Moto G3, with density 320: 

Image PNG: 3591px - 153px
ImageView: layout_width: 1780dp;
 layout_height: 153dp;

What would be the calculation for a device with 480 dpi density for example?

Comment: @PauloLinhares-Packapps I've added calculation for 480dp at the bottom of the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to 320 and other than 480. It was not clear to me these parameters calculations.

Comment: Krzysztof Skrzynecki: this will not only improve ruler image quality for each size and type of screen? Because this is already what we do normal for our images, so my image of the ruler, will have about 10cm visible on screen 320dpi (Moto G3), and a screen bigger it obviously would have to show more than 10cm visible the ruler and mater to ruler image in the same actual size it appears in Moto G3. By the logic of Android, your suggestion will show, for example, always 10cm visible image of the ruler, whether you opened the app in Moto g3 or a tablet 10 inch. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: You're wrong - visible part of ruler will be close to real screen height. You can use one image resource and **change ImageVIew height** to pixel size, which we've calculated above, e.g. for 480dp image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 5669;

Comment: your calculation logic does not give an exact value. But you next. For the device of 480dpi I realized that is 91.25% of the result of the calculation. But for other DPIs does not follow the same percentage, which makes me a lot because I do not have all these devices in the hands, and the emulator is not in the actual size of a device type. Give me some light on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @PauloLinhares-Packapps you're right - above solution just gives you approximated result - six general densities buckets (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and so on) defined in Android covers all of the Android devices and they just group devices with 'similar' density - e.g. take a look on mdpi in this picture https://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-ranges.png . Devices with about 150dp and about 200dp are both grouped to the same density bucket - mdpi

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you get your answers correct because it appears that previous answers were not satisfied. I had once the same problem - I need this `ImageView` to have the same size on a plethora of devices without scaling. I solved my problem by providing defined value in `dp` for `layout_width` and `layout_height`

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for run in multiscreen

Comment: No friend, I need to make a picture with fixed size, identical to the object size in the real world, a ruler for example. It can not change the size in different devices. That is, the support android can not grow or shrink this according to the screen or her density. Understood ?